# Compound verb in: He likes to sing and play

Tags: predicate

In the context of compound subjects and compound verbs, the subject below is *he*. However, the tricky thing here is the verb(s) of the predicate part. Since the first verb is *likes [to sing]* then the second should be *likes [to play]*. In other words the compound verb would not be *sing* and *play* but rather *likes to sing* and *likes to play*.

The original sentence and expanded forms are:

1. He **likes to sing and play**.
2. He likes to sing and likes to play.
3. He likes to sing and he likes to play.

The question is: what is the compound verb in sentence 1 above?

Comment: Unlike, say, [***to bow and scrape***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bow-and-scrape), I don't think anyone would say ***to like to sing*** or ***to sing and play*** were credible "compound verbs". So the short answer here is *there isn't one*.

Comment: The main verb of the sentence is *likes*. The compound direct object is *to sing and play*, two conjoined infinitives. The *to* of the second infinitive is elided and it's understood that the first *to* governs both infinitives. Infinitives are verb forms. You can tell because they're formed with the plain form of the verb and they do verbish things like take **objects** as in *He likes to play **the flute***. But infinitives take roles in sentences (like direct objects, as in your example) that are also played by nouns. Direct objects are considered part of a sentence's predicate.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that they are objects of the verb like. It is equivalent to: He likes playing and singing. Thanks

Comment: There is no compound verb in the given sentence. The only verb is 'likes' and it is a simple verb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no compound verb in *sentence 1*.
In this sentence, the subject is *he*,  the verb is *likes* and the (direct) object is (to) *sing and play*.
Infinitives may, of course, be used as nouns, and are so used here.
The other two sentences have the same verb (likes) repeated. I think that awkward.

I prefer *sentence 1* with only one stated verb . That is all that is needed.

Comment: +1 I like your short and simple intro: no compound verb in 1. Period. I didn't notice that they are objects of the verb like. It is equivalent to: He likes playing and singing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can coordinate two or more words or phrases of the same grammatical category to create a new word or phrase of that same category.  Your example 1 coordinates two verbs to create a verb "sing and play".  Your example 2 coordinates two verb phrases to create a verb phrase "likes to sing and likes to play".  Your example 3 coordinates two sentences to create a sentence "He likes to sing, and he likes to play."

I used the term "coordinate" instead of "compound" to avoid confusion with the term "compound verb" used to refer to a single word verb made by combining two words, like "stirfry" (see [Compound verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_verb)).

Answer (score 4):

In using the term *compound*, it may help to keep the distinction between the lexical classification of a word and its role in a sentence. The OP's example has a compound direct object

> to sing and [to] play

A direct object has a function in a sentence (namely to take the action of the main verb), and it's composed of two of infinitives (which are words of the lexical class *verb*). An alternate expression could contain a **compound main verb**

> He **plays and sings**

Compound verbs, on the other hand, are conjoined verbs that act together as a single verb with its own independent sense. These are rare in English. One response here has suggested

> bow and scrape

but this is really a set phrase of two separate verbs, with *scrape* meaning to bow awkwardly by drawing the foot back across the ground.

Another suggestion is *stirfry*, but this really means stirred frying, with the first verb acting as a modifier to the first.

About the only pure compound verb I can find is *go and do*, meaning to deliberately perform an action, usually one frowned on:

> He called the boss a jackass?  Did he really **go and do** that?

Note that this verb is an idiomatic unit, different from

> Did he really **go** to church **and do** an act of contrition?

Also note that both parts of the compound verb take tense:

> Yes, he called the boss a jackass. He really **went and did** it.